# How can I indent every sibling in an ul > li structure?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple structure that represents the parents of current navigation (like breadcrumbs).

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul > li ~ li:before {
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

/* I want to make this part dynamic to cover an infinite amount of child nodes: */
ul > li ~ li ~ li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul > li ~ li ~ li ~ li {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul > li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Parent #1</li>
<li>One more parent</li>
<li>Another parent</li>
<li>A very long item with potential page break,<br /> br tag just used as an example</li>
<li>Current item</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make the left padding of each li sibling 20px extra compared to the sibling before? I cannot change the html and I cannot use javascript.

Edit: The item text can have one or more lines (automatic word break, if the subject is to long). I've modified the example to cover the case where a line break occurs.

Comment: Will you always have exactly 4 li or will there be an arbitrary number of them?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The goal is an infinite/unknown amount of child items. A limit of four works without changing something.

Comment: I would nest `<ul>` inside each `<li>` this way would be more semantic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a counter, using system "symbolic".

In the snippet, I have used a visible symbol to show how it works.

Replace this with an Unicode symbol that is equivalent to whitespace, and you will have it working.

```css
@counter-style pad {
 system: symbolic;
 symbols:" ";   /* unicode U+2003 */
 suffix: " ";
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: section;  
}

ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul > li:nth-child(even):before {
  counter-increment: section;  
  content:  counter(section, pad) '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
 
}

ul > li:nth-child(1):before {
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 20px;
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3):before {
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 40px;
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
}
ul > li:nth-child(5):before {
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 60px;
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
}
ul > li:nth-child(7):before {
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 80px;
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
}
ul > li:nth-child(9):before {
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 100px;
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Parent #1</li>
<li>Parent #1</li>
<li>One more parent</li>
<li>One more parent</li>
<li>Another parent</li>
<li>Another parent</li>
<li>A very long item with potential page break,<br /> br tag just used as an example</li>
<li>A very long item with potential page break,<br /> br tag just used as an example</li>
<li>Current item</li>
<li>Current item</li>
</ul>
```

Another possibility is to use spaces as symbol, and set 'whitespace: pre' on the pseudo before:

```css
@counter-style pad {
 system: symbolic;
 symbols: '      ';
 suffix: " ";
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: section;  
}

ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul > li ~ li:before {
  counter-increment: section;  
  content:  counter(section, pad) ' ⤷';
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Parent #1</li>
<li>One more parent</li>
<li>Another parent</li>
<li>A very long item with potential page break,<br /> br tag just used as an example</li>
<li>Current item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or just use `color: transparent` for the symbols so that they aren't visible.

Comment: @SalmanA yes , of course. But it seems more "semantic" to use spaces, than to use some transparent text. (not that I care much about semantics, but..)

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer. It does not enable to add an exact padding and depends on font rendering size. I've not played with it yet, but may be it can be combined with letter-spacing attribute and the perfect amount of white spaces with zero width. So the font rendering does not matter. I don't know, if a letter spacing is applied to zero width spaces.

Comment: I have edited the first snippet. The li are duplicated, one using the counter for indent, the otrher using a hardcoded padding. They look pretty much the same. I have used the Unicode "EM space", that should have a dimesion of 1em.

Answer (score 4):

Use `float: left;`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li:before {
  content: '⤷';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Parent #1</li>
  <li>One more parent</li>
  <li>Another parent</li>
  <li>Current item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay, this is a neat trick. But it only works, if the :before text is higher than the item text. If the item text does have a second line the whole layout breaks. But I'll keep this idea.

Comment: @Lundstromski Nice trick, but it has some limits I think, for example if you give border to `lis`, the layout will breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the bounty notice mentions:

> If it cannot be done using current css features please tell me about
> current drafts or upcoming features.

I would like to mention that there is a feature request to [enable the use of counter() inside calc()](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1026) which is mentioned in [drafts as well](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-functions). If implemented, the following would work:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: child-counter;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5em;
  counter-increment: child-counter;
}
ul li:nth-child(n + 2)::before {
  content: "⤷";
  /* this won't work now but may be in the future */
  margin-left: calc(1em * counter-value(child-counter));
}
ul li:nth-child(n + 2)::after {
  content: "(counter = " counter(child-counter) ")"
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Parent #1</li>
  <li>One more parent</li>
  <li>Another parent</li>
  <li>A very long item with potential page break,<br /> br tag just used as an example</li>
  <li>Current item</li>
</ul>
```